# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

I've posted this same question on the meta of all the other sites undergoing elections, so just in case you've missed it I'm adding it here.

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

Comment: This makes me tempted to nominate myself, just so I can see the statistics on myself...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - I had that thought on Stack Overflow, but by that time there were 30+ candidates and I didn't really want the job anyway.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto, @ChrisF, as of yesterday you can add any users you like to the statistics. And as of a few days ago, you can choose other badges too. Note also that a lot of the numbers shown have *extra* statistics if you roll over them.